# How to display multiple Gridviews when clicked on link tag at the same position?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

[image]I have a page in which the left section has 4 link tags
Report 1
Report 2
Report 3 &
Report 4

When user clicks on Report 1 that particular Gridview 1 will be displayed...The same should happen with other Reports..How do I achieve this functionality in ASP.NET ? When user clicks on link tag Reports 2 it should display Gridview 2 in place of Gridview 1

Can someone please help me with the code.

Thanks.

Comment: do u have one gridview or different girdview for different report link

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to put update panel in which you can place your gridview for each link
and on click event 1st report link hide all the other three panel with their gridview

for example:

```
protected void Report1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Panel1.Visible= true;
    Panel2.Visible = false;
    Panel3.Visible = false;
    Panel3.Visible = false;
 }
```

for 2nd link

```
protected void Report2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Panel1.Visible= false;
    Panel2.Visible = true;
    Panel3.Visible = false;
    Panel3.Visible = false;
 }
```

and next for 3rd and 4th link also